# Jest Enzyme Mount error: refers to a value, but is being used as a type here ts(2749)

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am getting started with testing and I am really stuck in this thing.

I have a component

```
interface IFiltersInput {
    onChange?: (e: any) => void;
    onKeyUp?: (e: any) => void;
    value?: string;
    type?: string;
    id?: string;
    isInvalid?: boolean;
    name: string;
    label: string;
}
export const myInput: FunctionComponent<IFiltersInput> = (props) => {
    const btnGroupClasses = {...};

    if (props.type === 'number') {
        return (
            <div className='col-25'>
                <label className="label">{props.label}</label>
                <input
                    id={props.id}
                    className={btnGroupClasses}
                    onChange={props.onChange}
                    onKeyUp={props.onKeyUp}
                    value={props.value}
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div className='col-25'>
            <label className="label">{props.label}</label>
            <input
                type={props.type}
                id={props.id}
                className={btnGroupClasses}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                onKeyUp={props.onKeyUp}
                value={props.value}
            />
        </div>
    );

}
```

and then when I try to mount

```
describe('myFilter', () => {
    ...
    const component = mount(<myInput name='my-name' label='some-label' inInvalid={false} />);
    ...

});
```

And that's when I get an error myInput refers to a value, but is being used as a type here ts(2749).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and fixed it by changing my file extension from `.ts` to `.tsx`.